# nhibernate visual studio intellisense for easy mapping

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate

I see there are many tutorials about nhibernate

but I cannot find a descent one that explains only about mapping with nhibernate.

Is there any tutorial that explains all the used attributes? cascading, generator..
Is there a good intellisense to visual studio 2010 that allso explan about any attribute and attribute-value?

Comment: If you want intellisense on your mapping consider Fluent NHibernate which uses a code based fluent syntax for mapping rather than XML and attributes http://fluentnhibernate.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NHibernate Reference Documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html) is what you're looking for.

The mapping section starts at [Chapter 5](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping).

As for enabling intellisense for your mapping files, you can do so by setting the schema setting for `.hbm.xml` files to the `nhibernate-mapping.xsd` file.

[image]

Comment: cannot find this schema `properties`, where is it?

Comment: @EladBenda I just re-read your comment, these properties (Encoding, schema, output, stylesheet) will appear in the `properties window` once you open your `.hbm.xml` file in the code editor

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of the tags and attributes is [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html). It's not complete, but the important things are explained.

There is also explained how to enable intellisense:

> Tip: to enable IntelliSense for mapping and configuration files, copy
>   the appropriate .xsd files as part of any project in your solution,
>   (Build Action can be "None") or as "Solution Files" or in your "Lib"
>   folder and then add it to the Schemas property of the xml file. You
>   can copy it in \Xml\Schemas, take care
>   because you will have to deal with different version of the xsd for
>   different versions of NHibernate.